# using a loop to change color of pixels according to calculations

Tags: jython

I am just starting to learn jython, and just have a question which I cannot seem to get right.

From my text, I am to create a picture that is 640 x 480 pixels, and then, using a loop, pixel by pixel set the color to a calculation for r, g, b which we have already been given.
I can create a picture, I can set variables, however I cannot seem to go any further in creating a loop to set each pixel colour.
I know its only simple, but just wandering if anyone can help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

`xrange()` will create a generator which yields integers in a range. `for` will loop once per element of an iterable.

```
for row in xrange(480):
  for col in xrange(640):
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to iterate through the pixels.

```
  picture = makeEmptyPicture(400,200)
  pixels = getPixels(picture)
  #make an empty picture and get the pixels

  for px in getPixels(picture):
    x=getX(px)
    y=getY(px)
    r = (sin(x * radian * id[1]) * cos(y * radian * id[4]) + 1) * ord(StringID[0]) * 2.5
    g = (sin(x * radian * id[2]) * cos(y * radian * id[5]) + 1) * ord(StringID[0]) * 2.5
    b = (sin(x * radian * id[3]) * cos(y * radian * id[6]) + 1) * ord(StringID[0]) * 2.5
    newColor=makeColor(255 - r, 255 - g, 255 - b)
    setColor(px, newColor)
  show(picture)
  repaint(picture)
```